# Where can I find a list of latin words?

Tags: data-request, language, dictionary

I'm currently searching for a big list of machine readable latin words. I need it in a (.txt) file and preferably no definitions with the words, and each word be on a different line. For example:

```
studiose
studium
stultus
suadeo
suasoria
...and so on...
```

Does anyone know where I could find something like this or does someone have it? If you know of one with definitions, the would have to be commonly separated like with a colon:

```
latin_word:definition
```

Comment: I started to write an answer but then realized this was a waste of time, because it was based om **my** Google search for 'latin word list'. You can do the same. There are plenty.

Comment: What is a *big list*? Please give numbers.

Comment: If you need a list without definitions, why the colon requirement for a list 'with'? *Any* separator will do, because you can simply change it to a colon in any text editor.

Comment: Are you interested in word lists as words are used in classical texts (so including conjugations and declensions), or the only the root form of the word? An example: (A) only *aqua*, or (B) *aqua*, *aquae*, *aquam*, etc.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Latin may or may not be helpful

Answer (score 6):

You can get [8600 Latin words from Latin wikitionary](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?language=la&project=wiktionary&categories=Lingua%20Latina&ns%5B0%5D=1&sortby=title&interface_language=en&active_tab=tab_output&&doit=) or [879.898 Latin words from English wiktionary](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?language=en&project=wiktionary&depth=5&categories=Latin%20language&ns%5B0%5D=1&sortby=title&interface_language=en&active_tab=&doit=) using PetScan. You can change output to csv or tsv in the "Output" tab.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found any ready lists with just Latin words in txt format, but you can parse these lists to extract the Latin words from them:

- Dickinson College: [**LATIN CORE VOCABULARY**](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/latin-vocabulary-list). [Terms of use](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/terms-use): "(...) Dickinson College Commentaries by Dickinson College is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License (CC BY-SA)."
- Bill Casselman: [**Latin dictionary**](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/frivs/latin/latin-dict-full.html). Terms of use: contact the [author](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/).
- The Latin Dictionary: [**Index**](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/index). Terms: Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/word-lists/

They have tons of different word lists for multiple languages.

Comment: That's a Scrabble word-list site with no foreign languages, not to mention Latin.